# Code behaves differently in Android and Windows

Tags: android, delphi, graphics, bitmap, delphi-xe5

I try to draw on a bitmap. This works fine in Windows but creates a segmentation fault in Android (anyhow, that's what Delphi says, I just see no reaction on Android). I have a mobile project, form containing only a TToolbar, TSpeedButton, two TLabels and a TImage. There's just one eventhandler for the TSpeedButton click.

When I comment out everything below the comment the code works fine in Android. When I try to follow with the debugger the code works fine to the end of the procedure. without seeing a drawing or a segmantation fault. When I let it run on the fault occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure TForm2.Button_DrawClick (Sender: TObject);
var rct: TRectF;
    h, w: Int32;
begin
  h := Trunc (Image.Height);
  w := Trunc (Image.Width);
  Label_Height.Text := IntToStr (h);
  Label_Width .Text := IntToStr (w);
  rct := TRectF.Create(20, 20, w - 20, h - 20);
// can be commented out below //
  Image.Bitmap.Create (w, h);
  if Image.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    Image.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := $FF0000FF;
    Image.Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 3;
    Image.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawEllipse (rct, 20);
    Image.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := $FF00FF00;
    Image.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawRect(rct, 0, 0, AllCorners, 40);
  finally
    Image.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end; // try..finally
end; // Button_DrawClick //
```

Comment: `Image.Bitmap.Create (w, h);` doesn't look right to me. `Create` is a constructor, it shouldn't be used just for initializing of an existing object. Probably Android's VM accounts this as a construction of a new object and then performs a garbage collection. Try using `Image.Bitmap.SetSize(w, h)` instead.

Comment: @alex, you can with xe5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is wrong on all platforms.

```
Image.Bitmap.Create (w, h);
```

That runs the constructor on an already constructed instance. You don't want to do that. You might get away with it on some platforms but it's never right.

Set the bitmap dimensions like this:

```
Image.Bitmap.SetSize(w, h);
```

You may want to call Clear on the bitmap too.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not an error. "When a constructor is called using an object reference (rather than a class reference), it does not create an object. Instead, the constructor operates on the specified object, executing only the statements in the constructor's implementation, and then returns a reference to the object." --http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Methods

Comment: @Inspired No, it's an error. FMX `TBitmap` is not designed to support such use. The language permits it, but the class has to support it to. And it doesn't. And I'm reasonably sure that the language feature is not deprecated.

Comment: I got this code from embaradero help (and no, couldnt find back url). It still works on windows 7. Anyhow I tried with declaring bitmap:tbitmap, do a tbitmap.create and assign it to timage, same result: works in windows, not in android. If still considered wrong, what is right?

Comment: @David, it works! As I had tried SetSize before, resulting in segmentation fault, I paid at first no attention to your answer. After some experimenting I found that a SetSize *after* BeginScene results in a segment fault, *before* is ok as I did now. The Bitmap.Clear is not necessary on Windows, but it is on Android. Thanks for the hint. I copied my code from the Embarcadero sample code, see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/FMXTCanvasSaveCanvas_%28Delphi%29 and next look for FormCreate. There you'll find the Bitmap.Create.

Comment: The Emba code samples are shockingly poor quality. I think they were written by interns and nobody with any experience checked them.

Comment: Problem is that code works on windows, well, in my case. I took it as one of the changes of xe. How wrong can one be ;-)