# Painting bitmap with multiple threads, results different in Windows and Android

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe5

My app creates an image of a Mandelbrot fractal. It does so by computing rows of data, converting these to a row of colors and next copying this row to a bitmap. First this was done in a serial way and worked great. Now I am trying to do this with multiple threads. Each thread computes its own series of rows, e.g. thread 0 computes 0, 4, 8, 12, ...; thread 1: 1, 5, 9, ...; thread 2: 2, 6, 10, ..., thread 3: 3, 7,..., in the example given 4 threads are used (FMax_Threads = 4). A critical section (declared global) must prevent writing the bitmap at the same time by several threads. Another global variable (Finished_Tasks) is used to track the number of rows written. As soon as that equals the number of rows computing is done.

The same code works well under Windows and results in a garbled bitmap under Android. I noticed earlier that [Windows is somewhat more forgiving to errors than Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079037/code-behaves-differently-in-android-and-windows). Does someone know what exactly I am doing wrong?

The unit below computes the threaded mandelbrot

```
  unit Parallel_Mandelbrot;

  interface

  uses System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
       System.Variants, System.SyncObjs, System.Diagnostics, FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics;
  //     Color_Type_Defs;

  const cZoom_Factor = 3.0;
        cMax_Stack   = 100;

  type
     TPrecision = double;

     Trec_xy = record
        xl: TPrecision;
        yl: TPrecision;
        xu: TPrecision;
        yu: TPrecision;
     end; // Record: Trec_xy //

     TStack_xy = array [0..cMax_Stack + 1] of Trec_xy;

     TCompute = class;

     TParallelMandelbrot = class (TObject)
     private
        FBitmap: TBitmap;
        FXSteps: Int32;
        FYSteps: Int32;
        FMax_Iter: Int32;
        FMax_Threads: Int32;
        FColor_Pattern: Int32;
        FStop: boolean;
        FStack: TStack_xy;
        FCurrent_Stack: Int32;

        function  get_threads: Int32;
        procedure set_threads (value: Int32);
        function  get_iterations: Int32;
        procedure set_iterations (value: Int32);

     public
        constructor Create (Bitmap: TBitmap; xsteps, ysteps, max_iter, cp: uInt32);
        destructor  Destroy; override;
        procedure zoom (xc, yc: Int32);
        procedure unzoom;
        procedure reset;
        function compute (iterations: Int32): Int64;

        property Max_Threads: Int32 read get_threads write set_threads;
        property Iterations: Int32 read get_iterations write set_iterations;
        property Color_Pattern: Int32 read FColor_Pattern write FColor_Pattern;
        property Stop: boolean read FStop write FStop;
     end; // Class: ParallelMandelbrot //

     TCompute = class (TThread)
     protected
        FBitmap: TBitmap;
        Fxl: TPrecision;
        Fyl: TPrecision;
        Fxu: TPrecision;
        Fyu: TPrecision;
        FXSteps: Int32;
        FYSteps: Int32;
        FOffset: Int32;
        FIncr: Int32;
        FMax_Iter: uInt32;
        FColor_Pattern: Int32;

     public
        constructor Create (Bitmap: TBitmap; xl, yl, xu, yu: TPrecision; xsteps, ysteps, offset, incr, max_iter, cp: uInt32);
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Execute; override;
        procedure Work;
     end;// TComputer //

  implementation

  var cs: TCriticalSection;
      Tasks_Finished: Int32;

  {*******************************************************************
  *                                                                  *
  * Class: ParallelMandelbrot                                        *
  *                                                                  *
  ********************************************************************}

  constructor TParallelMandelbrot.Create (Bitmap: TBitmap; xsteps, ysteps, max_iter, cp: uInt32);
  begin
     inherited Create;

     FBitmap := Bitmap;
     FCurrent_Stack := 0;
     FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xl := -2.0;
     FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yl := -1.5;
     FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xu := +1.0;
     FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yu := +1.5;

     FXSteps := xsteps;
     FYSteps := ysteps;
     FMax_Iter := max_iter;
     FColor_Pattern := cp;
     FMax_Threads := 1;

  // Create a global critical section
     cs := TCriticalSection.Create;
  end; // Create //

  destructor TParallelMandelbrot.Destroy;
  begin
     cs.Free;

     inherited Destroy;
  end; // Destroy //

  function TParallelMandelbrot.get_threads: Int32;
  begin
     get_threads := FMax_Threads;
  end; // get_threads //

  procedure TParallelMandelbrot.set_threads (value: Int32);
  begin
     FMax_Threads := value;
  end; // set_threads //

  function TParallelMandelbrot.get_iterations: Int32;
  begin
     get_iterations := FMax_Iter;
  end; // set_iterations //

  procedure TParallelMandelbrot.set_iterations (value: Int32);
  begin
     FMax_Iter := value;
  end; // set_iterations //

  procedure TParallelMandelbrot.zoom (xc, yc: Int32);
  // Zooms factor zoom_factor into the fractal
  var rect: TRectF;
      xfraction, yfraction: TPrecision;
      xcenter, ycenter: TPrecision;
      xrange, yrange: TPrecision;
      xzoom, yzoom: TPrecision;
      offset: TPrecision;
  begin
     if FCurrent_Stack < cMax_Stack - 1 then
     begin
        xrange := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xu - FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xl;
        yrange := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yu - FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yl;
        xfraction := xc / FXsteps;
        yfraction := yc / FYsteps;
        xcenter := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xl + xfraction * (xrange);
        ycenter := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yl + yfraction * (yrange);
        xzoom := xrange / cZoom_Factor;
        yzoom := yrange / cZoom_Factor;

        FCurrent_Stack := FCurrent_Stack + 1;
        FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xl := xcenter - xzoom / 2;
        FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xu := xcenter + xzoom / 2;
        FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yl := ycenter - yzoom / 2;
        FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yu := ycenter + yzoom / 2;

  // Draw a dotted rectangle to indicate the area on the bitmap that is zoomed into
        FBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
        try
  // Create a rectangle with (Left, Top, Right, Bottom)
           offset := 2 * cZoom_Factor;
           rect := TRectf.Create(xc - FXSteps / offset, yc - FYSteps / offset,
                                 xc + FXSteps / offset, yc + FYSteps / offset);
           FBitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
           FBitmap.Canvas.StrokeDash := TStrokeDash.sdDot;
           FBitmap.Canvas.DrawRect(rect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 50);
        finally
           FBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
        end; // try..finally
     end; // if
  end; // mandel_zoom //

  procedure TParallelMandelbrot.unzoom;
  begin
     if FCurrent_Stack > 0 then
     begin
        FCurrent_Stack := FCurrent_Stack - 1;
     end; // if
  end; // mandel_unzoom //

  procedure TParallelMandelbrot.reset;
  begin
     FCurrent_Stack := 0;
  end; // reset //

  function TParallelMandelbrot.compute (iterations: Int32): Int64;
  var Timer: TStopWatch;
      threads: array of TCompute;
      thread: Int32;
      xs, ys: Int32;
      xl, yl, xu, yu: TPrecision;
  begin
     xl := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xl;
     yl := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yl;
     xu := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xu;
     yu := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yu;
     xs := FXSteps;
     ys := FYSteps;
     SetLength (threads, FMax_Threads);
     Tasks_Finished := 0; // No tasks finished yet
     Timer.Create;
     Timer.Reset;
     Timer.Start;
     FBitmap.SetSize (FXSteps, FYSteps);
     FBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene; // Tell the canvas we start drawing
     try
  // The threads are created suspended, so they have to be started explicitly
        for thread := 0 to Max_Threads - 1
           do threads [thread] := TCompute.Create (FBitmap, xl, yl, xu, yu, xs, ys, thread, Max_Threads, Iterations, Color_Pattern);
        for thread := 0 to Max_Threads - 1
           do threads [thread].Start;

  // Wait until all threads are ready. Each thread increments Tasks_Finished
  // when one row is computed
        while Tasks_Finished < FYSteps do
        begin
           Sleep (50);
        end; // while
     finally
        Timer.Stop;
        Result := Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        cs.Acquire; // Be absolutely sure all threads left the cirtical section
        try
           FBitmap.Canvas.EndScene; // and tell the canvas we're ready
        finally
           cs.Leave;
        end; // try..finally
     end; // try..finally
  end; // compute //

  {*******************************************************************
  *                                                                  *
  * Class: TCompute                                                  *
  *                                                                  *
  ********************************************************************}

  constructor TCompute.Create (Bitmap: TBitmap; xl, yl, xu, yu: TPrecision; xsteps, ysteps, offset, incr, max_iter, cp: uInt32);
  begin
     inherited Create (True); // Create suspended

     FBitmap := Bitmap;
     Fxl := xl;
     Fyl := yl;
     Fxu := xu;
     Fyu := yu;
     FXSteps := xsteps;
     FYSteps := ysteps;
     FOffset := offset;
     FIncr   := incr;
     FMax_Iter := max_iter;
     FColor_Pattern := cp;
  end; // Create //

  destructor TCompute.Destroy;
  begin
     inherited Destroy;
  end; // Destroy //

  procedure TCompute.Execute;
  begin
     try
        Work;
     except
        // A thread should never crash in Execute, just ignore the exception
     end;
  end; // Execute //

  procedure TCompute.Work;
  var vBitMapData: TBitmapData;
      row_of_colors: array of TAlphaColor;
      ix, iy: Int32;
      w, h: Int32;
      iter: uInt32;
      xl, yl, xu, yu: TPrecision;
      x, y: TPrecision;
      x0, y0: TPrecision;
      x2, y2: TPrecision;
      x_inc, y_inc: TPrecision;
      inv_max_iter: TPrecision;
      temp: TPrecision;
  begin
  // Initialize the bitmap size
     h := Round (FBitmap.Height);
     w := Round (FBitmap.Width);
     FXsteps := w;
     FYsteps := h;
     inv_max_iter := 1 / FMax_Iter;
     SetLength (row_of_colors, FXSteps);

     xl := Fxl;
     yl := Fyl;
     xu := Fxu;
     yu := Fyu;

  // compute the Mandelbrot image. Iterate row wise, as the bitmap is organized
  // row wise (first y, later x). This makes it easier to multi-thread the
  // computation in a later stage.
     x_inc := (xu - xl) / FXsteps;
     y_inc := (yu - yl) / FYsteps;

  // For each row (y) starting at FOffset, incremented with FIncr
     iy := FOffset;
     while iy < FYsteps do
     begin

  // Compute one column (x)
        ix := 0;
        while ix < FXsteps do
        begin
           x0 := xl + ix * x_inc;
           y0 := yl + iy * y_inc;
           x := 0;
           y := 0;
           x2 := 0;
           y2 := 0;
           iter := 0;
           while ((x2 + y2) < 4) and (iter < FMax_Iter) do
           begin
              temp := x2 - y2 + x0;
              y := 2 * x * y + y0;
              x := temp;
              x2 := Sqr (x);
              y2 := Sqr (y);
              iter := iter + 1;
           end; // while
           case iter mod 4 of // 4 shades of blue
              0: row_of_colors [ix] := $FFFFFFFF;
              1: row_of_colors [ix] := $FF4444FF;
              2: row_of_colors [ix] := $FF8888FF;
              3: row_of_colors [ix] := $FFCCCCFF;
           end; // case
  //         row_of_colors [ix] := create_color (iter * inv_max_iter, FColor_Pattern);
           ix := ix + 1;
        end; // while

  // Copy the computed row to the bitmap. Use the critical section to aquire
  // exclusive write rights to the bitmap
        cs.Acquire;
        try
           if FBitmap.Map (TMapAccess.maWrite, vBitMapData) then
           try
              for ix := 0 to FXSteps - 1
                 do vBitmapData.SetPixel (ix, iy, row_of_colors [ix]); // set the pixel color at x, y
           finally
              FBitmap.Unmap (vBitMapData);   // unlock the bitmap
           end; // if  try..finally
           Tasks_Finished := Tasks_Finished + 1;
        finally
           cs.Release;
        end; // try..finally

  // On to the next row
        iy := iy + FIncr;
     end; // while
  end; // Work //

  end. // Unit: Parallel_Mandelbrot //
```

And it is called as follows:

```
Mandel := TParallelMandelbrot.Create (Image.Bitmap, Round (Image.Width), Round (Image.Height), 255, 0);
Mandel.compute (32);
```

As you might have guessed Image is a TImage on the form.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update 1**
The remarks of LU RD and David made me to reconsider the algorithm. As a result of that I found that a FBitmap.Canvas.EndScene was missing in the TParallelMandelbrot.compute function. When I corrected that the app worked in both Windows and Android.

At first I removed an important bottleneck by using a matrix of TAlphoColor and copying this to the bitmap when all computations were done. That saved 5/8 to 3 times of the speed to redraw the bitmap, depending on the number of iterations (64 and 4096). The more iterations, the more computations, the less likely that a bottleneck occurs, nicely reflected in the figures. Another suggestion was to use WaitFor. That offered the possibility to remove the critical section and with that the bottleneck. As was the updating of Finished_Tasks the only statement left I could not find this back in the timing results. The code however, was greatly improved.

LU RD mentioned AlphaColorToScanline. As I got great results with ScanLine in the VCL days I expected to see great results. Not so now. I could not detect a difference between using a Scanline other than noise. Worse however is that in Android the Red and Blue bytes are swapped. In Windows they are deisplayed correctly.

I published the code below so you can check for yourself. Below some timing results (Windows = core i7-920 4 cores each with hyper thread, 2.67Ghz; Android = ARMv7, 1Ghz, 2(?) cores)

```
  # of    timings in seconds
  threads windows android
    1       5.5     30.0
    2       2.9     20.0
    4       1.6     19.7
    8       1.1       -
```

See compute in TParallelMandelbrot below. Mark the EndScene statement at the end which is added. Windows does not care very much, Android however, does. I now create the threads unsuspended, i needn't start them anymore. The improvements are hardly noticable.

```
  function TParallelMandelbrot.compute (iterations: Int32): Int64;
  var Timer: TStopWatch;
      vBitMapData: TBitmapData;
      threads: array of TCompute;
      thread: Int32;

      xi, yi: Int32;
      xs, ys: Int32;
      xl, yl, xu, yu: TPrecision;
  begin
     xl := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xl;
     yl := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yl;
     xu := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].xu;
     yu := FStack [FCurrent_Stack].yu;
     xs := FXSteps;
     ys := FYSteps;
     SetLength (threads, FMax_Threads);
     Timer.Create;
     Timer.Reset;
     Timer.Start;
     FBitmap.SetSize (FXSteps, FYSteps);

  // The threads are created suspended, so they have to be started explicitly
     for thread := 0 to Max_Threads - 1
        do threads [thread] := TCompute.Create (FColor_Matrix, xl, yl, xu, yu, xs, ys, thread, Max_Threads, Iterations, Color_Pattern);
     for thread := 0 to Max_Threads - 1
        do threads [thread].WaitFor;

     Timer.Stop;
     Result := Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
     FBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene; // Tell the canvas we start drawing
     try
        if FBitmap.Map (TMapAccess.maWrite, vBitMapData) then
        try
           for yi := 0 to ys - 1 do
           for xi := 0 to xs - 1 do
              vBitmapData.SetPixel (xi, yi, FColor_Matrix [yi, xi]); // set the pixel color at x, y
  //            AlphaColorToScanline (FColor_Matrix [yi], vBitmapData.GetScanline (yi), xs, pfA8R8G8B8);
        finally
           FBitmap.Unmap (vBitMapData);   // unlock the bitmap
        end; // if  try..finally
     finally
        FBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
     end; // try..finally
  end; // compute //
```

And the computing function in TCompute:

```
  procedure TCompute.Work;
  var ix, iy: Int32;
      iter: uInt32;
      xl, yl, xu, yu: TPrecision;
      x, y: TPrecision;
      x0, y0: TPrecision;
      x2, y2: TPrecision;
      x_inc, y_inc: TPrecision;
      inv_max_iter: TPrecision;
      temp: TPrecision;
  begin
  // Initialize the bitmap size
     inv_max_iter := 1 / FMax_Iter;

     xl := Fxl;
     yl := Fyl;
     xu := Fxu;
     yu := Fyu;

  // compute the Mandelbrot image. Iterate row wise, as the bitmap is organized
  // row wise (first y, later x). This makes it easier to multi-thread the
  // computation in a later stage.
     x_inc := (xu - xl) / FXsteps;
     y_inc := (yu - yl) / FYsteps;

  // For each row (y) starting at FOffset, incremented with FIncr
     iy := FOffset;
     while iy < FYsteps do
     begin

  // Compute one column (x)
        ix := 0;
        while ix < FXsteps do
        begin
           x0 := xl + ix * x_inc;
           y0 := yl + iy * y_inc;
           x := 0;
           y := 0;
           x2 := 0;
           y2 := 0;
           iter := 0;
           while ((x2 + y2) < 4) and (iter < FMax_Iter) do
           begin
              temp := x2 - y2 + x0;
              y := 2 * x * y + y0;
              x := temp;
              x2 := Sqr (x);
              y2 := Sqr (y);
              iter := iter + 1;
           end; // while
           FColor_Matrix [iy, ix] := create_color (iter * inv_max_iter, FColor_Pattern);
           ix := ix + 1;
        end; // while

  // On to the next row
        iy := iy + FIncr;
     end; // while
  end; // Work //
```

**Update 2**
The final verdict is that a TBitmap is *not* thread safe. See this [link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=82584) (it is somewhere on the Embarcadero wiki but couldn't refind it, this is the only reference I found). That explains why working with an intermediate colot matrix is such a good idea!

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: Every thread is serialized with a critical section when writing to the bitmap. Seems like a real bottleneck to me. Why not let the threads write to a common matrix of TAlphaColor. No protection needed since they write to different lines. When the threads are ready, the main thread can transfer the data into the bitmap in one step.

Comment: I was going to say exactly what @LURD said. Don't use a bitmap as your computation data structure. One thing to watch out for though is the danger of false sharing. But that's of second order import compared to addressing the point LURD made.

Comment: The forum [link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=82584) in your Update 2 no longer works - maybe there are other references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually know for sure why the code is failing on Android. But the most likely explanation is simply that you are performing GUI work away from the main thread. You are doing that because you are operating on the `TImage` bitmap away from the main thread.

In any case, using a shared bitmap and a critical section to gather the results of your Mandlebrot calculation is massively inefficient. You are serializing all your threads on the critical section just so that they can write to separate parts of the bitmap.

As LURD mentioned in the comments, you can simply remove that bottleneck. Have your threads gather their results to a shared matrix of colours. Since each thread handles an entire row in its entirety, there no data races, and you can remove the critical section. Once all threads are complete, you can then blit the matrix onto the bitmap and the job is done. I presume that you can do this efficiently in FMX using scan line techniques.

One possible scaling hindrance is that you could get false sharing if one thread operates on the end of row `i` whilst another thread operates at the beginning of row `i+1`. Deal with that by getting thread 1 to process rows `0..(N/k)-1`, thread 2 to process rows `(N/k)..(2N/k)-1` etc. where N is the row count, and k is the thread count. In other words get each thread to process contiguous rows.

Some more comments:

1. You have the classic data race on `Tasks_Finished`. Using `InterlockedIncrement` to update that would resolve that problem. However, you don't need the variable at all.
2. You don't need `Tasks_Finished` because your waiting method is weak. Simply wait for each thread to finish by calling `WaitFor` on the thread. Do that in a loop for all threads. This is known as *joining*. On Windows there are efficient mechanism for joining multiple threads, but the RTL does not expose them. Since you are cross-platform, a simple loop across the threads calling `WaitFor` will suffice.
3. You are suppressing exceptions in your thread procedure. Perhaps your Android code is throwing them, and you suppress them. The `TThread` class already catches any exceptions and stores them in `FatalException`. You should remove the exception handler in your `Execute` method and check whether or not `FatalException` is assigned upon completion.
4. It seems pointless to create your threads suspended, and only start them when you've finished creating all of them. Why make your threads wait like that? That can only delay progress. Create the threads non-suspended and let them get straight to business.
5. Why use a fixed size stack? Surely it would be far easier to use `TStack<T>` which is built for the job.

Comment: +1, [`AlphaColorToScanline`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.PixelFormats.AlphaColorToScanline) seems to do the data transfer efficiently.

Comment: The real reason for the strange Android behavior is that I forgot to add a FBitmap.Canvas.EndScene at the and of the computations of TParallelMandelbrot. As mentioned before, Windows is more forgiving than Android. Though the correct answer is not mentioned I will accept this as the correct answer as your remarks and those of LU RD forced me to optimize the algorithm and during that process I discovered my error. Thank you, David and LU RD. AlphaColorToScanline did not help, see the update.